# Get the value at specific point in Matplotlib contourf plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to retrieve the value at an arbitrary location on a contourf plot, where the coordinate of the location is not necessarily a member of the input data.

Using the matplotlib documentation example here:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html#contour-plot-of-irregularly-spaced-data

How do you retrieve the value at say  x = -.74 and y = 0.11 to use later in the program?  ( need value in a variable, not the cursor readout from imshow)

Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at 2d interpolation?
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Comment: That is an option, but not sure the interpolation schemes are the same. If not, then we would likely end up with different values, especially in areas with highly variable gradients. It seems to me if matplotlib has already done the heavy lifting of interpolation, then there should be a way to retrieve the already computed value that appears in the plot.